# Can't install caret package

Tags: r

I'm not sure what's happening here but the caret package is not installing properly. I realize similar problems have been posted before but I can't figure it out.

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
cannot open file 'C:/Users/John Compton/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/MASS/R/MASS.rdb': No such file or directory
```

So I've been trying to figure this out. I have the fully updated R 3.6.1, I also ran a thing that I've since lost of like install.packages("caret", repos = "cran/....", c = ("Dependencies", "Suggestions")) which took about 30 minutes and installed like every suggested package, so I don't know what the error could be. How do I fix the error with this package?

Edit: To include the install.package call

```
> install.packages("caret")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/John Compton/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/caret_6.0-84.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 6237886 bytes (5.9 MB)
downloaded 5.9 MB

package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\John Compton\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGuKafa\downloaded_packages
>
```

Comment: can you paste the log from install.packages("caret")

Comment: does `library(MASS)` work?

Comment: library(MASS) hits the same error, although I've been able to call library for some packages like ggplot2 or lattice fine

Comment: what happens if you do `remove.packages('MASS')` and then `install.packages('MASS')` what is the error?

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much. Are those packages interrelated? Do you know why that might have been an error?

Comment: Yes looks like `caret` uses a few functions from `MASS`.The clue to the error was: `cannot open file 'C:/Users/John Compton/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/MASS/R/MASS.rdb': No such file or directory` but not sure why that file was missing for you